# Why can't I save my @Entity User with it's UserRepository in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring

### Problem

Invoking `repository.save(user);` where `repository` is an instance of `UserRepository` and `user.toString` is `User[id=0, userName='asd', password='asd']`, my controller gives the following error:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invoked method public abstract java.lang.Object org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(java.lang.Object) is no accessor method!] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invoked method public abstract java.lang.Object org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(java.lang.Object) is no accessor method!
```

### Details

I know `repository.save(new User("user1", "pass1"));` works because I tested my repository using:

```
public CommandLineRunner demo(UserRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {
                // save a couple of users
                repository.save(new User("user1", "pass1"));
                repository.save(new User("user2", "pass2"));
                }
}
```

Here's the full Request mapping of the page:

```
RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showRegistrationForm(WebRequest request, Model model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "registrations/register";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerUserAccount(WebRequest request,
                                        @ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user,
                                        BindingResult result,
                                        UserRepository repository) {
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {

          System.out.println(user);
                repository.save(user);
        }
        return "redirect:/";

}
```

And here's the UserRepository:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findByUserName(String UserName);
}
```

And here's the User @Entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    protected User() {}

    public User(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    // standard getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "User[id=%d, userName='%s', password='%s']",
                id, userName, password);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the `UserRepository repository` in code of Controller should not be used as parameter:
...

```
public String registerUserAccount(WebRequest request,
                                        @ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user,
                                        BindingResult result,
                                        UserRepository repository)
```

...

Can you just use @Autowired it like:

```
@Autowired 
 private UserRepository repository;
```

And then try again?!

Hope this help.

Comment: It works! You beautiful, beautiful man! Now please explain why it works!

Comment: Good to know that it works for you. Some details are: UserRepository is extended from CrudRepository. So, the bean will be created automatically and it is used as a dependency in Controller via @Autowired. Spring does not regconized the dependency as a parameter in the request. Most of the time, I just use the model in it. Hope it help.